# Threadsafe method in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I feel like this is probably already answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it or maybe I'm not using the right keywords.

What I want to do is an initialize a value in a `Servlet Filter` with as little blocking as  possible. I am by no means an expert in threads, so here is what I came up with:

```
private static Object getObject() {
    if(OBJECT == null) {
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            InputStream is = getInputStream("path_to_file");
            OBJECT = loadObject(is);
        }
    }
    return OBJECT;
}
```

This method is used within the Servlet Filter, which will be called by multiple threads at once. I want to make sure that I load this when it is needed, and not on the `init` method.

My question is, is this thread safe? Once it is initialized I think it'll be good, but I want to make sure that it works when it's being initialized.

PS: Please redirect me to any question that already answers this if they exist. Thanks!

Comment: Why not initialize it at app startup?

Comment: That was my first idea, but by other constraints in the project I can't do that. I know it's bad :)

Comment: @Rob Ok, your comment made me see that the problem is quite deeper than I expected. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use the `init` method:

> The servlet container calls the init method
>   **exactly once** after instantiating the filter. The init method must
>   complete successfully before the filter is asked to do any filtering
>   work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig)

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
     // read the file here, this method will be called only once
}
```